# Set struct field with function pointer in C

Tags: c, struct, initialization, function-pointers, function-call

I'm messing around with C and i would like to simulate a constructor for a class but using C.
I've a structure with two fields, one `int` and a pointer to a function, like this

```
typedef struct elem {
    int a;
    void (*initVal)(struct elem*);
} element;
```

The function `initVal` is the following

```
void initVal(struct elem* el) {
    el->a = 5;
}
```

The main idea behind this function is to set the field `a` of the struct itself to 5.
In the main:

```
int main() {
    element a;
    (a.initVal)(&a);
    printf("%d\n", a.a);

    return 0;
}
```

My goal i to have printed `5` in the main, but this program throws a runtime error. What is wrong here? Is it possible to call a function pointer to set a field of the structure where it is defined in? Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an uninitialized pointer in this statement

```
(a.initVal)(&a)
```

You need to write

```
void initVal(struct elem* el) {
    el->a = 5;
}

//...

element a;
a.initVal = initVal;

a.initVal( &a );
```

Or

```
element a = { .initVal = initVal };
a.initVal( &a );
```